# string format check

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

Suppose I have string variables like following:

```
s1="10$" 
s2="10$ I am a student"
s3="10$Good"
s4="10$       Nice weekend!"
```

As you see above, `s2` and `s4` have white space(s) after `10$` .

Generally, I would like to have a way to check if a string **start** with `10$` and have **white-space(s) after** `10$` . For example, The rule should find `s2` and `s4` in my above case. how to define such rule to check if a string start with '10$' and have white space(s) after?

What I mean is something like `s2.RULE?` should return true or false to tell if it is the matched string.

**----------  update -------------------**

please also tell the solution if `10#` is used instead of `10$`

Comment: Smells like homework. It is considered good practice to tag homework questions as "homework", and to include the source code YOU have written to show you have made an attempt to solve the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this using [Regular Expressions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) (Ruby has Perl-style regular expressions, to be exact).

```
# For ease of demonstration, I've moved your strings into an array
strings = [
  "10$",
  "10$ I am a student",
  "10$Good",
  "10$       Nice weekend!"
]

p strings.find_all { |s| s =~ /\A10\$[ \t]+/ }
```

The regular expression breaks down like this:

- The `/` at the beginning and the end tell Ruby that everything in between is part of the regular expression
- `\A` matches the beginning of a string
- The `10` is matched verbatim
- `\$` means to match a `$` verbatim. We need to escape it since `$` has a special meaning in regular expressions.
- `[ \t]+` means "match at least one blank and/or tab"

So this regular expressions says "Match every string that starts with `10$` followed by at least one blank or tab character". Using the `=~` you can test strings in Ruby against this expression. `=~` will return a non-nil value, which evaluates to true if used in a conditional like `if`.

*Edit*: Updated white space matching as per [Asmageddon's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/867814/asmageddon) suggestion.

Comment: \s will also match newlines, I would use [\t\ ] instead.

Comment: If the string contains '#' instead of '$' do I need to escape # by \# or not?

Comment: No, `#` is not a special character. The [Ruby QuickRef](http://www.zenspider.com/Languages/Ruby/QuickRef.html#12) has a list of all the special characters that you need to watch out for.

Comment: I updated my post.I tried "10#    hello"==~ /\A10#\s+/ , but it returns to me false, which I expected true

Comment: You used `==~`, which doesn't do what you want. You want `=~` (note that there is only one equal sign).

Comment: Very clear answer, +1 for the detailed explanation of the regular expression being used. thank you!

Answer (score 1):

this works:

```
"10$ " =~ /^10\$ +/
```

and returns either `nil`  when `false` or `0` when `true`. Thanks to Ruby's rule, you can use it directly.

Answer (score 1):

Use a regular expression like this one:

```
/10\$\s+/
```

**EDIT**

If you use =~ for matching, note that

> The =~ operator returns the character position in the string of the
>   start of the match

So it might return 0 to denote a match. Only a return of nil means no match.

See for example http://www.regular-expressions.info/ruby.html on a regular expression tutorial for ruby.

Comment: `10\$+` could  match `$10$10$10` which would be weird :) +1 anyway

Comment: If the string contains '#' instead of '$' do I need to escape # by \# or not?

Comment: No - # is not a reserved character, but $ is (it denotes end of line if not escaped).

Comment: That checks for string equality. Use =~ to match regular expressions. Note the caveat I added to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to proceed to cases with **$** and **#** then try this regular expression:

```
/^10[\$#] +/
```